# What is 68A MeV for a xyz reaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I am reading a research paper and to explain an experimental data, the author has written....
The 68A MeV Li + p scattering data are reanalysed.....

I understand that A = atomic mass but how do I read this?
Is it something like 68 MeV beam is used? But then why did they write A?

I am a bit new to this. Sorry if it’s a stupid question.

Comment: Pulling up some papers, I find sentences like: "proton elastic scatterings of neutron rich nuclei 9Li and 11Li have been measured for the first time at Elab/A=60 and 62 MeV" - they are just specifying the energy in relevant units.

Comment: @JonCuster do they mean xyz MeV per nucleon?

Comment: That is how I read it. Lots of ways of reporting the energy. Is it the energy of the protons out of the accelerator? Is it in the center-of-mass frame for the interaction? I suspect that community went down the path of Elab/A so that proton scattering could easily be compared across multiple target nuclei.